# Change RecyclerView CardView background to transparent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, transparent, android-cardview, cardview

***Problem Short Version:***

> I want to make my CardView and RecyclerView background transparent, so
>   the fragment/activity background should become visible.

***Explained:***

I have an activity **A** with background image and fragment **B** is replaced on its **Framelayout**  , in Fragment **B** i have **recyclerView** which with **CardView** now problem is i want to make **every background transparent** so only CardView will be visible with actual background of activity

***RecyclerView look like this(These white background should be transparent) :***
[image: recyclerView_Card]

## Code

*Activity(A)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

*Fragment(B) RecyclerView*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        tools:listitem="@layout/layout_video_item"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_not_found"
        android:text="No Media Found Yet"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*CardView / Item layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        style="@style/CardView.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/media_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_delete"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/share_button"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ib_delete"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_video_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Title Test"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_ribbon"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/media_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ribbon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="New"
                android:textColor="@color/colorIcons"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_path"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="subtitle test"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/media_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_video_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_is_audio"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/media_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_duration"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_voice_black_24dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_is_video"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_is_audio"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_is_audio"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_is_audio"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_theaters" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_is_gif"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_is_video"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_is_video"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_is_video"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gif" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="0:00"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/media_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_path" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_size"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="0 MB"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_duration"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_duration"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_duration" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*Reason for asking question:*

I know there are lots of SO question out there to get this same task done but my requirements are little different and reason for asking this question is nothing is working for me.

*Expectation*

Comment: what's backgroundColor of Framelayout in Activity?

Comment: @Pavya so your suggestion is to assign color from my resources instead of android's ? i've tried that doesn't work `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/customColorTransparent"`

Comment: @FrameLayout replacing fragment have these background `android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: paste your activity xml

Comment: did you try to make framelayout transparent in activity xml?

Comment: @Nikunj sure its added now , yes rainmaker i have , check question again

Comment: style="@style/CardView.Light" may be affecting the situation remove it or just the part where background is set and see what happens

Comment: @Rainmaker no effect after removing style from CardView , either

Answer (score 0):

Set CardView Background to `app:cardBackgroundColor="#00ffffff"`

Comment: @ZulqurnainJutt also set recyclerview background to #00ffffff

Comment: tried that too didn't worked , sorry for late response

Comment: if you want fragment background to show then all upper layer should be transparent